# How to make Filter applicable only to a Module

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I have various modules in my Application such as Authentication , Tickets , Reports ---etc .
I want to apply Filters only to the Authentication Module and not to any other Modules .
I have written a Authentication filter , My question is that , how can i apply this Authentication Filter applicable only to Authentication Module .

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>AuthenFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>AuthenFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>test-param</param-name>
      <param-value>Initialization Paramter</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>AuthenFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**What should be under the url-pattern tag so that its applicable only to the AuthenFilter Module**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map your filter to particular URI, like this:

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>AuthenFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/modules/login</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

or

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>AuthenFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/modules/authentication/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: So ypu mean to say that  all the login related jsp's should be kept under login folder ? and What else we need to  keep under /modules/login folder ?? Is servlets should be also kept under serlvets fier

Comment: You may also check request's URI inside the filter, with no effect for unrelated resources.